# Make a time series plot in grafana with multiple lines

Tags: sql, grafana

I have a db with tables like:
table1:
| id | datetime | group |
|---|---|---|
|0|2022-07-14 06:03:05.000|1|
|0|2022-07-14 05:02:05.000|1|
|0|2022-07-14 05:01:05.000|2|
|0|2022-07-14 04:03:05.000|1|
|0|2022-07-14 04:02:05.000|2|
|0|2022-07-14 04:01:05.000|3|
|0|2022-07-14 03:03:05.000|1|

groups:
| name | info |
|---|---|
|1|'sdfdsf'|
|2|'dsfdsfsd'|
|3|'234234'|

I want to plot a graph with a count of rows in table1 for each group for interval of 1 hour. Like [this (can't past as image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isoWb.png)

I made this SQL query:

```
    select d.dt, coalesce(count(table1.id), 0) as count, g.group
    from (
        select generate_series(date_trunc('hour', timestamp '${__from:date}'), date_trunc('hour', timestamp '${__to:date}'), '1 hour') as dt
    ) as d(dt)
    left join (
        select distinct name from groups
    ) as g(group) on true
    left join table1 on table1.date >= d.dt and table1.date < d.dt + interval '1 hour' and table1.group = g.group
    group by 1, 3
    order by 1
```

It returns table like this:
| dt | count | group |
|---|---|---|
|2022-07-14 06:00:00.000|1|1|
|2022-07-14 06:00:00.000|0|2|
|2022-07-14 06:00:00.000|0|3|
|2022-07-14 05:00:00.000|1|1|
|2022-07-14 05:00:00.000|2|2|
|2022-07-14 05:00:00.000|0|3|

But grafana doesn't split this series with group column. It shows a single line like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTFfC.png)
How can I fix it?